# How to get User email address using user_login from wp-user in wortdpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get user email from wp-user table in wordpress?

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', 'admin' );
echo 'User is ' . $user->user_email.;
```

It's Not working.

Thanx & Regards

Comment: get_user_by() returns user data by field and data, are you trying to achieve current user's email id?

Comment: I want to retrieve all user's email not current user's.

Comment: try  `var_dump($user)` to see what is returned

Comment: updated my answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Since you want to retrieve a user based on username and get_user_by is not working you can try this:

```
global $wpdb;
$username = 'admin';
$email = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
SELECT user_email 
FROM $wpdb->users 
WHERE user_login = %s
", 
$username
) );

echo "$username's email is: $email";
```

Comment: But i want to retrieve user email using user_login. Ex:-Means when user name is admin then i get it's email admin@admin.com

Comment: i thought you want to retrieve all user's email? let me revise my answer

Comment: I want to retrieve particular one user's email using his/her name. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get user data by field and data

```
$user = get_user_by( $field, $value );
```

For example: you get user date with email is example@gmail.com

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'example@gmail.com' );
echo 'User is ' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
```

To get more user data, you use to print_r

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'example@gmail.com' );
print_r($user);
```

Comment: This query is not working for user email.it's only get username and lastname using email.But i want user email using user_login from wp-user.

Comment: This is Parameters $field('id', 'slug', 'email', or 'login'). That all wordpress support

Comment: I know this,i had try this but it's not working.Thanks